# check which entry is focused (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter

I am working with Python v3.4 and using `Tkinter` library to workout my GUI.

I have included an on-screen keyboard in my python app. The problem is as follow:

They are three entries:

```
username = Entry(root,font="Verdana 22")

password = Entry(root, font="Verdana 22")

courrierEntry = Entry(root, font="Verdana 22")
```

Below is the keyboard

```
 def select(value):
        if value == "BACK":
            entry2 = len(username.get()[:-1])

        username.delete(entry2, END)

    elif value == " Space ":
            username.insert(END, ' ')

    elif value == " Tab ":
            username.insert(END, '    ')

    else:
            username.insert(END, value)

buttons = [
    'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','l','o','p','BACK','7','8','9','-',
    'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','[',']','4','5','6','+',
    'z', 'x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.','?','1','2','3','/','HELP',
    ]

varRow = 2
varColumn = 0

for button in buttons:

    command = lambda x = button: select(x)
    keyboardButton = Button(keyboardFrame, text = button, width = 8,  bg="#795548", fg="#ffffff",
            activebackground="#D7CCC8",activeforeground="#000000",relief = "raised", padx=0,font="Verdana 11 bold",
            pady=8, bd=8, command = command)
    keyboardButton.grid(row = varRow, column = varColumn)
    varColumn += 1
    if varColumn > 14 and varRow == 2:
        varColumn = 0
        varRow += 1
    if varColumn > 14 and varRow == 3:
        varColumn = 0
        varRow +=1
```

As you may have notice in the keyboard, it only refers to the `username entry`, and hence even when not focused on the `username entry` whenever a button is pressed only the `username entry` reacts.

I would want that to establish some kind of if statement, the problem is that I am not familiar with verifying if the entry is focused/selected. It should go by the entry currently selected and not by name. So essentially whenever I select I can type.

Update:

## ------KEYBOARD----------

```
#checking to see whcih input entry is currently focused
inputFocus = None

def currentEntry(userEntry):
    global inputFocus
    inputFocus = userEntry

username.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda: currentEntry(username))
password.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda: currentEntry(password))
courrierEntry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda: currentEntry(courrierEntry))


def select(value):
    if value == "BACK":
        entry2 = len(inputFocus.get()[:-1])

        inputFocus.delete(entry2, END)

    elif value == " Space ":
            inputFocus.insert(END, ' ')

    elif value == " Tab ":
            inputFocus.insert(END, '    ')

    else:
            inputFocus.insert(END, value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `keyboardFrame.focus_get()` to get the window object that has the focus.

Comment: thanks and how would i adjust my select(value) function

Comment: @user3907211: `widget=keyboardFrame.focus_get(); widget.insert(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i meant particularly within the if statement of select function

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to remember the last Entry that had focus.
Because pressing a button will give the focus to the button.

```
hasFocus = None

def currentEntry(myEntry):
    global hasFocus 
    hasFocus = myEntry

username.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda myEvent: currentEntry(username)) # do the same for the other entries
```

Then use hasFocus in select.

NB: you probably wish to add 
`if inputFocus != None:` in select because at the beginning, there is no selected Entry.

Comment: thank you. I am just getting one small error: Unresolved reference 'FocusIn'

Comment: This is a bit of overkill, since tkinter already remembers which widget has focus. There's really no need to track it yourself.

Comment: @user3907211: sorry, forgot the quotes.

Comment: thanks for that, i've added the updated code under the update section of my initial post. It doesn't seem to respond and receive errors such as  in select
    inputFocus.insert(END, value)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: @user3907211: now it works. I also forgot that the function in bind takes an event as argument.